# Spring Boot: SpringBootServletInitializer posibly deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im working with spring boot `2.2.4.RELEASE`, looks that this release no longer supports `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer` since im facing problems with the class.

I've worked with this previous release `2.2.2.RELEASE` so it seems very strange since I cant found any doc online.

**EDIT**

This code does not work on the current release 2.2.4

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurityApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

IDE (STS 3.8.4) Error

```
The import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer cannot be resolved
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.kevinvjn</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-rest-basic-auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <WebLogic-Application-Version>${project.version}</WebLogic-Application-Version>
                            <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                        </manifestEntries>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>false</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: It still exists and is not deprecated according the [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/support/SpringBootServletInitializer.html).

Comment: Can't make it work propertly when usign `2.2.4.RELEASE` when I downgrade the version there is no problem.

Comment: What is not working? You should describe how you know that you have a problem.

Comment: updated question.

Comment: How are you managing your dependencies? Maven? It looks to me like your IDE didn't update the dependencies correctly.

Comment: It is an IDE problem. What IDE are you using? How do you configure class path - manually, via Maven plugin, via Gradle plugin?

Comment: I'm using maven to manage dependencies and STS as my IDE, updated question btw.